# Issue of using outlook2000 unit in Delphi

Tags: delphi, outlook, try-except

Am trying to use the unit 'outlook2000' but something wrong happned to my
**Try statements** and I get **Error: E2021 Class type required** .
if I excuted my app without this unit or without **Except** then everything is fine .

```
Uses ...,outlook2000;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
S:string;
begin
try
s:='Hello';
Except On E:Exception do
ShowMessage(E.Message);

end;
end;
```

Can anyboady explains what is the wrong .
Am using Delphi 10.1 Berlin , Win 10.

[image]

Comment: What is the context of this code? Unit initialization? a function or procedure? or what? IOW, please provide an [mre]

Comment: its inside onClick event for button ..

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Yes, I can reproduce the error in Delphi 10.4 CE. Will see if I can find the cause of it. Actually, I get another error: `Message` is highlighted and error message is  "E2003 Undeclared identifier 'Message'".

Comment: Moving the `Outlook2000` reference before `Sytem.SysUtils` removes the error message, but may of course introduce other errors. Only recommended for experimental purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason I know this is because just the other day this baffled me as well with a similar situation.

Change your `Except On:Exception` to `except on E:System.SysUtils.Exception`.
It's because the outlook2000 unit also has an interface called `Exception` but we're looking for the object declared in `SysUtils`.

Comment: Nitpick: not "object", but "class".

Comment: I think that this will give the solution to this issue .. but so far its not a good solution as it will cause unnecessary additional code in the units , and to those who has finished there project and they wish to add outlook services to their application they had to modify all of their Try statements .. thank you for your solution and good explanation.